# Align <h1> with <nav> in Html5

Tags: css, html, text-align

could you help me please to adjust that lines?

I'm just trying to align  ("LOGO") with  ("ITEM 1 - ITEM 2 -ITEM 3") but I can't do it well. Do you know how can modify the css file in order to do it?

Here there is my code with the snippet:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
}

main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#first-nav {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 6px 1em;
}

 #first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
 
#second-nav {
 padding: 4px 1em;
 height: 100px;
}

 #second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
 }
  
 #main-navigation {
  float: right;
 }

  #main-navigation a {
   color: #000;
   padding-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <section id="navigation">
    <nav id="first-nav">
     <a href="#">element 1</a>
     <a href="#">element 2</a>
     <a href="#">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="second-nav">
     <h1>LOGO</h1>
     <nav id="main-navigation">
      <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
     </nav>
    </section>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to align them vertically or horizontally?

Comment: align means you want all in the same line?

Comment: Vertically @nicholas79171

Comment: Exactly! @Rohit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#first-nav {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 6px 1em;
}

#first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

#second-nav {
  padding: 4px 1em;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}

#second-nav h1, #second-nav nav {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#second-nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#main-navigation a {
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="navigation">
    <nav id="first-nav">
      <a href="#">element 1</a>
      <a href="#">element 2</a>
      <a href="#">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="second-nav">
      <h1>LOGO</h1>
      <nav id="main-navigation">
        <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
        <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
        <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
      </nav>
    </section>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you! @Quertiy

Comment: @TimPoret, if this answer solves you problem, accept it by clicking a check mark on the left of it. By the way, you can add any margings you want (including 0) for the logo and/or navigation section.

Comment: @TimPoret, or an answer with flexbox.

Answer (score 2):

Use `display: flex` on `#second-nav` with `align-items: center;` and `margin-left: auto;` on `#main-navigation`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#first-nav {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 6px 1em;
}
#first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
#second-nav {
  padding: 4px 1em;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
#second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
}
#main-navigation {
  margin-left: auto;
}
#main-navigation a {
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <section id="navigation">
      <nav id="first-nav">
        <a href="#">element 1</a>
        <a href="#">element 2</a>
        <a href="#">element 3</a>
      </nav>
      <section id="second-nav">
        <h1>LOGO</h1>
        <nav id="main-navigation">
          <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
          <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
          <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
        </nav>
      </section>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice version! Flex are great!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers add styles to certain elements by default. In this case, there was margin being applied to the H1. I removed it.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
}

main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#first-nav {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 6px 1em;
}

 #first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
 
#second-nav {
 padding: 15px 1em 4px 1em; /* Add more space to top of nav */
 height: 100px;
}

 #second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
                margin: 0; /* Remove the margin */
 }
  
 #main-navigation {
  float: right;
                padding-top: .25em; /* pad the top to align right nav */
 }

  #main-navigation a {
   color: #000;
   padding-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <section id="navigation">
    <nav id="first-nav">
     <a href="#">element 1</a>
     <a href="#">element 2</a>
     <a href="#">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="second-nav">
     <h1>LOGO</h1>
     <nav id="main-navigation">
      <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
     </nav>
    </section>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to have more space between the black section and logo and the same for the items?

Comment: Font-size is different, so margin won't help.

Comment: It just needed padding.

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin-top:0px` to **h1** logo.

Comment: Please try to provide context with your answer.  A standalone answer may solve a problem in this specific scenario, but an explanation may solve many future problems.  Try to include what you think is causing the issue and why your answer will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin:0` to `h1`. By default browsers add margin to HTML elements so you need to adjust as per your requirements.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
}

main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#first-nav {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 6px 1em;
}

 #first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
 
#second-nav {
 padding: 4px 1em;
 height: 100px;
}

 #second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  display: inline-block;
        margin:0;
 }
  
 #main-navigation {
  float: right;
 }

  #main-navigation a {
   color: #000;
   padding-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <section id="navigation">
    <nav id="first-nav">
     <a href="#">element 1</a>
     <a href="#">element 2</a>
     <a href="#">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="second-nav">
     <h1>LOGO</h1>
     <nav id="main-navigation">
      <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
     </nav>
    </section>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:table` for the section element and `display:table-cell` for their childs.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: gray;
}

main {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 80%;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#first-nav {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #FFF;
 padding: 6px 1em;
}

 #first-nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding-right: 1em;
 }
 
#second-nav {
 padding: 4px 1em;
 height: 100px;
display:table;
}

 #second-nav h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  display: table-cell;
 }
  
 #main-navigation {
  display:table-cell;
 }

  #main-navigation a {
   color: #000;
   padding-left: 1em;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  <main>
   <section id="navigation">
    <nav id="first-nav">
     <a href="#">element 1</a>
     <a href="#">element 2</a>
     <a href="#">element 3</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="second-nav">
     <h1>LOGO</h1>
     <nav id="main-navigation">
      <a href="#">ITEM 1</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 2</a>
      <a href="#">ITEM 3</a>
     </nav>
    </section>
   </section>
  </main>
 </body>
</html>
```